# Select default camera in custom layout in Zxing

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using `ZXing` to scan barcode in a `Xamarin Forms` app in a custom layout. How can I select the default camera as front camera. Their is no option to select the default camera.

```
    <zxing:ZXingScannerView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" IsScanning="true" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"  />
```

Comment: Why would you want to use the front camera?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the `Options` which is of type `MobileBarcodeScanningOptions`. That has a property called `UseFrontCameraIfAvailable`.

To set it from code, do this: `_scanView.Options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = true; }`

From XAML is a bit more extensive but not undoable:

```
<zxing:ZXingScannerView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" IsScanning="true" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200">
    <zxing:ZXingScannerView.Options>
        <zxcore:MobileBarcodeScanningOptions UseFrontCameraIfAvailable="true" />
    </zxing:ZXingScannerView.Options>
</zxing:ZXingScannerView>
```

You might need to import a different XAML namespace for the options object. I don't have an actual project at hand to try, but I'm sure you will figure that one out.